# Why operation is push for dismissViewControllerAnimated

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

I need to dismiss presented NavigationController with default animation, and I need custom animation on push. Here is what i'm doing:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    self.navigationController.delegate = self;
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    self.navigationController.delegate = nil;
}

- (IBAction)closeButtonTouchUp:(id)sender {
    [self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
}

- (id <UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning>)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController
                                   animationControllerForOperation:(UINavigationControllerOperation)operation
                                                fromViewController:(UIViewController *)fromVC
                                                  toViewController:(UIViewController *)toVC {
    if(operation == UINavigationControllerOperationPush) {
        return [TurnAnimationController new];
    }
    return nil;
}
```

But operation is always = Push, on push and on dismiss. Is it right? I can check `toViewController` instead of checking operation type but it will spoil code. Please suggest me some workaround?

Comment: Add your solution as an answer. It might help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

There was two different actions attached to the close button by mistake. That was leading to custom animation while dismiss.